# Update Initial Props on Reload in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I have a React Native application (Android) that returns some initial props from my activity delegate:

```
public class MainReactActivityDelegate extends ReactActivityDelegate {
    ...
    @android.support.annotation.Nullable
    @Override
    protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
        Bundle initialProps = new Bundle();
        count = ...; // count is stored in disk somewhere
        initialProps.putString("count", count );

        return initialProps;
    }
    ...
}
```

I then increment `count` in one of my components which works fine but when I shake to reload `getLaunchOptions` does not get called and the initial value of `1` is used.

Is there a hook in which I can update what the initial props are when reloading the app?

Comment: I don't think reloading will fully restart your app. Have you tried it with killing it manually and open it again?

Answer (score 5):

The way react native works, simply put, is as following;

1. The native application starts, methods such as getLaunchOptions gets called.
2. Javascript VM starts running
3. Your JS bundle code starts to be interpreted by the JS VM
4. Application starts running (JS VM talks with native thread and all the other magic)

When you shake to reload, or activate hot reloading on that matter, you are essentially skipping steps 1 and 2. So, any state or changes for JS code, you experience them as if you have restarted your application but *not the native state and / or changes*. Because of that you need to kill the app and start it again, from the android / ios itself to see the effect you want.